# Create HTML snapshot on AWS EC2 instance for Google rendering

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, rendering, google-crawlers

How can I create an HTML snapshot, server side, to provide it to Google for rendering(Crawling) and I have to do it on AWS EC2 instance which is the headless server. 
So how should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer for it:

```
    String Xport = System.getProperty("lmportal.xvfb.id", ":99");
final File firefoxPath = new File(System.getProperty("lmportal.deploy.firefox.path", "/opt/firefox/firefox"));
FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary(firefoxPath);
firefoxBinary.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", Xport);

FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxBinary,null);

driver.get(url);

Thread.sleep(1500);
res.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
String str = driver.getPageSource();
out.println(str);

out.close();
driver.quit();
```

And install the xvfb and firefox on your ec2 instance thats inportant.....